# Passing file path argument to a CherryPy

Tags: python, url, cherrypy

In CherryPy how do you pass an argument like file path (i.e. /abc/def/ghi) through a URL? I want to do something like `http://...../filepath="abc/def/ghi"`. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about using ~ as a delimiter and then just replace ~ in the string with /...

```
http://...../filepath=abc~def~ghi

def SomePage(self, filepath=None):
    filepath.replace('~', '/')
    return 'HelloWorld'
```

Hope this helps,

Andrew

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the reply. Indeed it's the same workaround suggested in the CherryPy documentation and it works.But i'm wondering if there is a way to pass the path keeping the slashes...In the meanwhile i keep this solution, thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help!  Welome to stackoverflow!  If my answer solved your problem please mark it as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `.../a/b/x=y` is the wrong way to send a value regardless of whether it is a file name or not. The correct way would be `.../a/b?x=y` 
or `.../a/b/?x=y` which would make `x` a standard query parameter  and cherrypy would treat it as such. Thereafter whether there were slashes in the value of `x` or not would be moot. They would get through to your code just fine.